# Duplicating and reusing Wordpress Site on Local Host

Tags: wordpress, localhost, cloning

I have duplicated and downloaded my current live WP site to the local host on my computer.  I want to use this site to create another site by revising existing content and image and eventually upload it to a different host with a new url.  What is the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed XAMPP\LAMPP
you can use your computer as web-server, and open your website in the browser from your local web server

1) you must unpack files into some folder

for example

`d:/www/docs/mywebsite`

2) restore the database from backup using your local phpmyadmin, console command or some MysqlDatabase environment

3) do changes in config.php according to your local Database credentials

4) configure your apache: add two virtual hosts **new_domain.com** and **old_domain.com**

for windows, you must add such lines at the end of

d:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@old_domain.com
        DocumentRoot d:/www/docs/mywebsite
        ServerName old_domain.com
        ServerAlias www.old_domain.com
        ErrorLog @rel_logfiledir@/old_domain.com-error_log
        CustomLog @rel_logfiledir@/old_domain.com-access_log common
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@new_domain.com
        DocumentRoot d:/www/docs/mywebsite
        ServerName new_domain.com
        ServerAlias www.new_domain.com
        ErrorLog @rel_logfiledir@/new_domain.com-error_log
        CustomLog @rel_logfiledir@/new_domain.com-access_log common
    </VirtualHost>
```

it is not mistaken ald_domain and new_domain must be configured to the same work dir

for Linux almost similar create two config files in /etc/apache2/site-enabled

5) restart Apache

6) add such four lines at the end of the hosts file

- if you are using Windows OS you can find the file

  `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- if you are using Linux you can find the file

  `/etc/hosts`

add such four lines at the end of the hosts file

`127.0.0.1 new_domain.com
127.0.0.1 www.new_domain.com
127.0.0.1 old_domain.com
127.0.0.1 www.old_domain.com`

7) using command line try

`ping new_domain.com
ping old_domain.com`

and each time you must see

`Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`

8) now open in your browser old_domain.com

if you do all above clearly you will see you old_domain site in your browser opened from your local web-server

9) login into your WP admin panel

install plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-domain-changer/

and change domain according to plugin instruction

and you will see that domain will be changed from old_domain.com to new_domain.com

10) now you can develop your new web site and after finishing developing backup it and upload to the new server